# Objective C - Is it possible to call a category's method from another category of same type?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

I would like to know if it is viable to actually call a category's method in another category of same type. I've tried doing so, but that does not seem to work. I want to know that is it a proper way or at least is it possible?

For ex:

**CategoryA file**

```
@implementation UIImage (UIImage+CategoryA)

-(void)doThis {
    NSLog(@"Something....");
}
```

**CategoryB file**

```
#import "UIImage+CategoryA.h"

@implementation UIImage (UIImage+CategoryB)

-(void)someMethod {
    [self doThis]; // Can I do this?
}
```

Any discussion/answers/insights are welcome.

Comment: What does "does not seem to work" mean?

Comment: That looks like it should work. What's the error you're getting?

Comment: I am getting compiler error: No visible @interface for 'UIImage' declares the selector 'doThis'.

Comment: What does `UIImage+CategoryA.h` look like? Did you actually declare `doThis` in it?

Comment: Yep I’ve declared it `-(void)doThis;` in the .h file. Suspicious of Xcode not properly indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A category adds methods to the original class. This is Objective-C so there's no concept of access control: once they exist, they are accessible to everybody. Therefore anybody with a pointer to an instance of the class and knowledge of the category can call them. That includes methods implemented in other categories of the same class.

So, yes, it is possible.

Comment: Shoot. As I suspected, the problem was with improper Xcode indexing. After cleaning and restarting Xcode, all went fine (face palm). Need to stick to the basics. Thanks for answering. :)